# Django: Form for each entry of a model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement a form to edit a field 'comments' for each entry of a given model, which is in my case 'Rental'.

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    returned = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    issue_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " - " + self.object.name
```

I don't take input for comments when making a new record but the user should have an option to give a comment afterwards. I need to make multiple forms and user should be able to write a comment and submit it using a button exactly next to the box.

I tried using formset and inlineformset but they don't do what I need. Is there any other way to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What made it so formsets didn't work?

Comment: I wanted to edit existing records with each record having its own submit button and I couldn't find a way to so with formsets using docs or google.

Comment: Each have their own submit button that just saves it and refreshes the page? You can create a list of forms with a hidden input that you provide a default Rental ID to, then in the views save just find and update that record.

Comment: yes exactly! That is what I need.